# How to connect to Oracle database on AWS EC2

Tags: linux, firewall, amazon-web-services

I have an Oracle 12C database on an EC2 instance running Oracle Linux 7.
The EC2 instance is in a public subnet and it has a public dns name  and a public IP address.

The listner.ora has proper host name of the server( ip-x.x.x.x.ec2.internal).

SQLnet.ora on server has below entry -

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

I have configured the EC2 security group with inbound rule to allow port 1521 from anywhere.

I can connect to the database using SQL Developer tool and sqlplus on the server it self. But I cannot connect from other EC2 instance ( bound to the same security group) or another Windows 10 machine outside AWS.

telnet  1521 never succeeds..

My question: Do I need to open port 1521 in the firewall on the Linux server in addition to having the inbound rules in the security groups ?

Comment: If there is a firewall on the Linux server then of course it needs to have the necessary ports open. Also check the output of `netstat` and see what IP the oracle DB server is bound to. If I remember right it only binds to localhost by default, but I don’t remember the details right now.

Comment: Is there a way to verify  if firewall is blocking the 1521 traffic? From AWS documentation it appears Security Group inbound rules are sufficient to open the ports.

Comment: If the firewall is on the server it doesn’t have anything to do with AWS. Just like all servers and computers they have the option to install a firewall. Your server might have `iptables` or something else. You’re going to have to do some research as opening your database server up to the world is not something you should do nonchalantly and you need to understand these things.

Comment: Thanks! This is just a test machine with no real data. Will post back the netstat output.

Comment: `netstat -ln` that’s the whole command

Comment: I didn't know the ports to be opened in the firewall in addition to configuring the inbound rules in the security group. 
After all, I didn't have to do that for ssh port 22.  
I followed the below thread and opened port ands now I am able to connect to the EC2 instance running Oracle databas!
https://serverfault.com/questions/450841/on-aws-do-i-have-to-open-ports-in-an-ec2-instances-firewall-as-well-as-security

iptables -I INPUT 3 -s *.*.*.*/* -d *.*.*.*/* -p tcp --dport 1521 -m state --state New -j ACCEPT   
/sbin/service iptables save

Comment: @Appleoddity your comment helped me resolve my issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another layer of security. SSH or DMZ + Load Balancing is the way to go. If not Make sure the following are all open for the IP. firewall, VPC Network, AWS inbound outbound rules.